# Удаление скрипта, запущенного с помощью getScript

Tags: javascript

Есть ли универсальные способы по удалению загруженного скрипта средствами jQuery? Имеется динамическая подгрузка страниц, и на некоторых есть скрипты, которые заодно со страницами загружаются и выполняются, но при переходе на другую страницу это скрипты не нужны (некоторые из них при неоднократном открытии попросту нагружают комп).

Можно ли определить в каком интервале памяти находится загруженный скрипт из getScript или eval и удалить его оттуда?

П.С. не думаю, что составление списка переменных и функция для каждого js файла, а потом по нему удаление) будет найс

Answer (score 1):

Запущенный скрипт не удаляется из памяти удалением его тега. Удаление  происходит - отключением всех перехватчиков событий ранее установленных, и удалением ссылок на объекты скрипта. нравится вам это или нет,но это так работает.

Хорошие модули/библиотеки имееют метод destroy который в отличных модулях даже работает как надо.

По поводу загрузки динамического контента, не грузите скрипты динамически. Это вредно. Может только загрузка jsonp имеет смысл.

Comment: с чего это вредно? Не буду же я при заставлять пользователя загружать все js скрипты при первом входе